# D3.js visual selecting image URL from object array dataset

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I've created myself a simple bar chart (I say simple but even this took me a VERY long time haha)

I've managed to append an image URL to the end of each bar within the chart.

Here is the [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/bentham7246/9yu0wenk/4)

Currently this is only using 1 image:
 `return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"`

However, i've created a second dataset "`dataset2`" which is an array containing `category`, `Value` and `URLimage`.

I'm looking for help in substituting "`dataset`" with "`dataset2`" so that I can use the array data and pull the `URLimage` from the array for each category

```
var w = 750;
            var h = 300;
            var barPadding = 2;

            var dataset = [18, 15, 13, 11, 12, 15, 20,25,30];

  /*var dataset = [
                            {"category": "A", "Value":18, "URLimage":https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png},
                            {"category": "B", "Value":15, "URLimage":https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png},
                            {"category": "C", "Value":13, "URLimage":https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png},
                            {"category": "D", "Value":11, "URLimage":https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png},
                            {"category": "E", "Value":12, "URLimage":https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png},
                            {"category": "F", "Value":15, "URLimage":https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png},            
                            {"category": "G", "Value":20, "URLimage":https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png},
                            {"category": "H", "Value":25, "URLimage":https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png},      
                      {"category": "H", "Value":30, "URLimage":https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png}  ] */

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            svg.selectAll("rect")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return i * (w / dataset.length);
               })
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - (d * 10);
               })
               .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
               .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return d * 10;
               })


                svg.selectAll(".images")
        .data(dataset)
      .enter().append("svg:image")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return i * (w / dataset.length)+18 ;
               })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - (d * 10);
               })
                .attr("width", 40)
                .attr("height", 40)
                .attr("xlink:href", function(d){
                return "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to do this is to take advantage of the fact that D3 [passes the datum `d` AND the index `i` to each selection](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_attr). Consequently, you can use the index to access the corresponding value in `dataset2`:

```
.attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
  return dataset2[i].URLimage
});
```

(Note that it might also be easy to just merge the two dataset variables together.)

Here's a full working example with a small change to your code. I'm using a picture of a basketball for the second bar so you can be sure it's working.

```js
var w = 750;
var h = 300;
var barPadding = 2;

var dataset = [18, 15, 13, 11, 12, 15, 20, 25, 30];

var dataset2 = [{
    "category": "A",
    "Value": 18,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "B",
    "Value": 15,
    "URLimage": "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Ftooelecity.org%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F03%2FBasketball.png&f=1&nofb=1"
  },
  {
    "category": "C",
    "Value": 13,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "D",
    "Value": 11,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "E",
    "Value": 12,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "F",
    "Value": 15,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "G",
    "Value": 20,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "H",
    "Value": 25,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "H",
    "Value": 30,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  }
]

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * (w / dataset.length);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d * 10);
  })
  .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d * 10;
  })


svg.selectAll(".images")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append("svg:image")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * (w / dataset.length) + 18;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d * 10);
  })
  .attr("width", 40)
  .attr("height", 40)
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
    return dataset2[i].URLimage
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: excellent...thank you very much.    You mentioned about merging the two datasets,  and I think that is my next step so that all the data is coming from the same variable.   I've tried adding in "dataset2[i].Value.length" to the code but that doesn't seem to work.  Is it different syntax?

Comment: If you are using the `Values` in `dataset2` instead of `dataset`, then you can access the value with `d.Value`, and you can use `dataset2.length` just as you were doing before.